# xCode Detail View is Empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, master-detail

I am creating an iPad application (iOS6.1) which has a master detail view concept. First view is a table view has list of items that are been loaded from Plist, when each row gets selected the second table view gets loaded with another Plist. theirs is my Detail view which has to display an UIView with a UILabel ans an UIImage. I am using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method . The first two table Views are been displayed properly and loads the row and display corresponding View but the last detail view which is supposed to display the UILabel and an image is empty, can any one help me to solve this problem

[image: My application flow]

My Code for the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method is

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

 {

TaskDetailViewController *newTaskDetailViewController = [[TaskDetailViewController alloc] init];

// pass the row to newDetailViewController

if (weekNumber == 0)
{
    newTaskDetailViewController.taskdescription = [weeklist1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
if (weekNumber == 1)
{
    newTaskDetailViewController.taskdescription = [weeklist2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}

if (weekNumber == 2)
{
    newTaskDetailViewController.taskdescription = [weeklist3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
// ...... repeated for 39 times because of the list


 newTaskDetailViewController.taskNumber = indexPath.row;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newTaskDetailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

DetailView header

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TaskDetailViewController : UIViewController

@property int taskNumber;

@property(strong , nonatomic) NSString *taskdescription;

@property (nonatomic , strong) NSMutableDictionary * tasks;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *questionImage;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *displayText;

@end
```

Implemetation file has

```
@implementation TaskDetailViewController

@synthesize taskNumber;

@synthesize taskdescription;

@synthesize tasks;

@synthesize displayText;

@synthesize questionImage;


-(void)viewDidLoad

{

[super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

self.title = taskdescription;

NSLog(@"%@", taskdescription);

}
```

Comment: Without seeing the code for did select row or the code for segue depending to if you are using xib or storyboard, it would be almost impossible to answer your question.

Comment: this was the code i am using

Comment: Syntax error before 3rd `if` -> Remove `}`

Comment: I can't see the deceleration of the label and the image, which in turn perhaps they should be strings in detail view and in did select row they should reference in your if statement. Your detail view can't show anything because nothing is being passed to it.

Comment: My detail view header file has the following code

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is using alloc init to create an instance of TaskDetailViewController. You've created that controller in the storyboard so you should instantiate it from the storyboard using an identifier that you give it (DetailViewController in my example):

```
TaskDetailViewController *newTaskDetailViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
```

Comment: i get the following error Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <UINavigationController: 0x1e8862d0>.

Comment: @LoreliaNithianandan  Did you add the identifier in the storyboard, and make sure it's spelled the same as what you have in code?

Comment: @LoreliaNithianandan, I can't tell what the problem is then -- this is the correct way to instantiate a controller in the storyboard. If you've set the identifier in the storyboard, and it matches what you have in the above method, this should work. You should add a log of self.storyboard to make sure it's not nil.